# How to prove that there exists a $z_0 \in U_{1} [0]$ such $ \prod_{k=1}^{n} |z_0 - a_k | \geq 1 $ for $a_1, \dots , a_n \in U_{1} [0] $?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, inequality

Let $a_1 , \dots , a_n $ be points in the unit circle/ball in $\mathbb{C}$ around $(0,0)$ (also known as $U_{1} [0]$), which do not necessarily differ from one another. How to prove that there exists some $z_0 \in U_{1} [0] $ such that $$ \prod_{k=1}^{n} |z_0 - a_k| \geq 1 ? $$
Here's what I tried thus far: First, pick a $z_0$ such that $|z_0 - a_j| \geq 1 $ for some $1 \leq j \leq n$. Then pick another point $a_k$ on the unit cirle. By the triangle inequality, we know that $|a_j - a_k| + |z_0 - a_k | \geq |z_0 - a_j| \geq 1 $, so $|z_0 - a_k | \geq 1 - |a_j - a_k| $. Therefore, we find that $$ \prod_{k=1}^{n} |z_0 - a_k | \geq |z_0 - a_j| \cdot \prod_{k=1 , k \neq j }^{n} (1 - |a_j - a_k| ) \geq  \prod_{k=1 , k \neq j }^{n} (1 - |a_j - a_k| ) .$$

I don't know how to proceed from here though. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your assumption on $a_1,\dots,a_n$, or equivalently, the notation $U_1[0]$, is a little ambiguous. Do you mean $|a_k|=1$(i.e. on the unit circle) or $|a_k|\le 1$(in the closed unit disk(ball))? Anyway, the conclusion holds for arbitrary $a_k\in\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @Landscape Ah I should have written on $|a_k|$ = 1 (on the unit circle). Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I see. You are welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conclusion holds for any $a_1,\dots,a_n\in\mathbb{C}$, not necessarily to be in the closed unit disk(ball).

To see this, let $f(z)=\prod_{k=1}^n(z-a_k)$, and it suffices to show that 
$$M:=\max_{|z|=1}|f(z)|\ge 1.\tag{1}$$
By [Cauchy's integral formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula), 
$$n!=f^{(n)}(0)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz.\tag{2}$$
From $(2)$ we know that
$$1=\big|\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz\big|\le\frac{1}{2\pi }\int_{|z|=1}|f(z)||dz|\le M,\tag{3}$$
which completes the proof.

**Remark:** $(3)$ also implies that $M=1$ if and only if $f(z)=z^n$, i.e. $a_k=0$ for $k=1,\dots,n$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(z)=\Pi(z-z_k)=z^n+\dots+f_0$. Let $\xi_j$ be the roots $\xi^{n+1}=1$. Since
$$
\sum_{j=0}^n f(\xi_j)=(n+1)f_0,
$$
you can find some $\xi_j$ such that $|f(\xi_j)|\ge 1$.

Comment: A nice more elementary argument than mine, +1! A comment: be careful about $f_0$, which has no lower bound. Nevertheless, this gap could be fixed by playing some trick with the definition of $f$.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't realizing that $|z_k|=1$ in your argument(as a condition given in the question) when I wrote the last comment. Anyway, applying your idea to $\frac{f(z)}{z^n}=\prod(1-z_k/z)$ with $|z|=1$ gives the same result for any $z_k\in\mathbb{C}$. :)